# How to inject Application in play controller without causing circular dependecies

Tags: playframework

When I try to use the application for class loading in a play framework controller as described in the documentation. I get circular dependecies.

```
public class MyController extends Controller {

  @Inject 
  public MyController(Application app) {
    app.classloader();
  }
}
```

Does a better way for classloading exist or a way to break the cyclic dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Circular dependencies could be resolved by injecting Provider.

Example code:

```java
public class MyController extends Controller {

    @Inject 
    public MyController(Provider<Application> app) {
        app.get().classloader();
    }

}
```

More information about this is in [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/JavaDependencyInjection#Managing-circular-dependencies)